# Prevent proxy initialization when accessing @Id field via method with JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'd like to let my entities implement a certain interface, which returns the id:

```
public interface IdentifiableEntity<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    public T getIdentifier();
}
```

But if I do so and the entity is lazy-loaded, `getIdentifier()` initializes the proxy (and causes a separate select). Here's an example entity:

```
@Entity
public class AppFile implements IdentifiableEntity<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    public Long getIdentifier() {
        return id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    ...

}
```

Is there a way to tell Hibernate/JPA that `getIdentifier()` only accesses the well-known ID and there is no need to initialize the proxy?

What I already found out:

1. When I annotate the properties (getters) instead of all fields, `getId()` will not initialize the proxy.
2. Using `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` on `private Long id;` it will behave as 1. without the requirement to annotate everything on property level.

**UPDATE:**
Both 1. and 2. do not satisfy my requirements yet, namely:

- `getIdentifier()` returns the id without proxy initialization
- The field `id` does not change its name (because of a lot of existing JPQL statements).

Comment: could you tell why 1. and 2. are not feasable for you?

Comment: Would you like to do that `Hibernate/JPA` call `getIdentifier()` method when `EntityManager` does operation?

Comment: @CycDemo No. I'd like to be able to call `getIdentifier()` after EntityManager is closed without proxy init (and the exception it causes).

Comment: in NHibernate one can specify its own Proxy type. Maybe this can be done in hibernate too?

Answer (score 0):

`getId()` method to initialize the proxy, it just need to redirect `getIdentifier()` method.

```
public Long getId() {
    return getIdentifier();
}
```

Comment: I would need it the other way round, but calling `getIdentifier()` would cause proxy init.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you use annotations on fields you could use Java Reflection API to access directly the id value. Here i use org.easytesting fest-reflect API (a thin wrapper around the Reflection API) to make the code shorter.
The id value in under proxy.handler.id.
My Example is an Employee with a ManyToOne to a Department (the potential proxy).
In my case the id(s) are always Long ....

```
public Long extractIdFromDepartment(Employee employee) {

    Long idDepartment = null;

    Department departement = employee.getDepartment();
    Boolean isNotProxy = Persistence.getPersistenceUtil().isLoaded(departement);

    if (isNotProxy) {
        // here, department is not a proxy
        // a direct access is always ok
        idDepartment = departement.getId();
    } else {
        // here department IS a proxy
        // works in all cases : with Hibernate/JPA annotations on getters or fields.
        javassist.util.proxy.MethodHandler handler = Reflection.field("handler")
                .ofType(javassist.util.proxy.MethodHandler.class).in(departement).get();
        java.io.Serializable idDep = Reflection.field("id").ofType(java.io.Serializable.class).in(handler).get();
        if (idDep instanceof Long) {
            idDepartment = (Long) idDep;
        }
    }
    return idDepartment;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well its 4 years later, but this would be solution:

@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class AppFile implements IdentifiableEntity {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
private Long id;


   public Long getId(){
       return id; 
   }
```

now calling `getId()` on entity will not initialize its proxy.